# How to extract the word after the dot

Tags: java

I have a String shown in below format

```
String str = "query at.dddimin ntoreturn:1 reslen:1833 nscanned:1  nquery: { like_symbol: \"SC!JNJ\" }  nreturned:1 bytes:1817";
```

i need to extract the word after the dot `at` shown above, so that the output should be "**dddimin**"

I tried this way

```
String[] result = str.split("\\.");

System.out.println(result[1]);
```

But the output i am getting is below

```
dddimin ntoreturn:1 reslen:1833 nscanned:1  nquery: { unique_symbol: "SC!JNJ" }  nreturned:1 bytes:1817
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i get the word after the dot .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a general approach to solving string pattern matching problems, consider using regular expressions. In the following code, the regular expression `\.(\S+)` is stating: find a match of a string that starts with a dot and is followed by one or more characters that are not spaces, and capture the characters after the dot in a group. In Java, this would be written as follows:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.(\\S+)");
Matcher match = regex.matcher(str);
if (match.find())
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

The `match.group(1)` expression will return the expected result:

```
dddimin
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int dot = str.indexOf('.')+1;
String result = str.substring(dot,str.substring(dot).indexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `split()`, your regex needs to split by both dots and spaces in this case:

```
String[] result = str.split("\\ |\\.");
assertEquals("dddimin", result[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int dot = str.indexOf('.');
String result = str.substring(dot + 1, dot + str.substring(dot).indexOf(' '));
```